# Dynamically allocated string array, then change it's value?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to create a string array and use a pointer to modify it. I'm not sure how to declare the pointer since strings can vary in length, and I think this is what causes the error.

My code looks something like this:

```
#includes <string>
#includes <iostream>
using namespace std;

string *users = NULL;
int seatNum = NULL;
cin >> seatNum;
users = new string[seatNum];
string name;
cin >> name;
users[seatNum] = name;
```

It throws me an Write Access Violation when I try to change its value. From what I've read it's because strings are compiled as read-only, so my question is how would I/what would I do to change it? Easy-to-understand explanations would be preferable.

Comment: `users = new string[seatNum];` creates an array of strings indexed from `0` to `seatNum - 1`, so `users[seatNum]` accesses past the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're accessing memory beyond the range of the allocated array

```
users = new string[seatNum];
users[seatNum] = name;
```

The first element is [0]. The last is [seatNum-1]

Comment: Doh, I have no idea how I could overlook something as simple as this. Sometimes I guess you just have to ask someone, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You have created an array of `seatNum` elements. Array element indexing starts at `0` therefore the range of valid indexes is `[0, seatNum - 1]`. By accessing `users[seatNum] = ...` you are effectively going past the last valid element of the array. This invokes UB (undefined behavior).

---

I see you have already made the right choice of using `std::string` instead of C-style strings. Why not make the same choice over arrays?

```
#include <string>
#include <array> 
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char*[]) {
    int seatNum = 0;
    std::cin >> seatNum;
    std::vector<std::string> users(seatNum);
    std::cin >> users[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Try to avoid pointers and C-style arrays, especially dynamic ones.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. int seatNum will be allocated on the stack and will never be NULL. You should set it to 0.
2. You are setting users[seatNum] which is out of bounds causing your program to crash. You
   can only use indices from 0 to seatNum-1.

Updated: Chris is correct. I looked into it and strings are indeed mutable in C++.

Comment: The last point isn't really correct. Strings are mutable in C++, so there's no reason to create a copy. It just modifies the object in question. Whether that means doing a deep copy of the contained characters varies.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you cannot set null value to int type data

```c
int seatNum = NULL; // wrong 
int seatNum = 0;  // right
```

secondly string bounds from 0 to seatnum -1

```c
users[seatNum-1] = name; // right
```